# Very sensitive dim led indicator detector

Tags: diodes

Background: My car aircon recirculation button often turns off by itself. This happens when the aircon is cold enough. Problem is. When it turns off and the indicator light disappears, the pollution outside gets into my car and I can smell the pollution and my pm2.5 monitor registers 20x higher.

I need to build a very sensitive dim led indicator detector to trigger a buzzer if the light turns off below.

[image]

What kind of photon detector can I fit into the almost 2 inches round button so if it detects the light is turns on it will sound a buzzer alerting one to it?

Comment: That is plenty of light if the sensor is close to the source, it doesn't need to be overly sensitive. A common photodiode should be able to do this. The trick is shielding from sunlight which will overwhelm the sensor.

Comment: Can you give an example of a common photodiode that can do that and optimal transistor to trigger an alarm?

Comment: Are you going to build this inside the button or attach it to the outside? Do you want to detect if the light is turned off intentionally or if the lamp fails? Your comment changed your question...now you want a circuit to trigger an alarm. You should explain completely and in detail what it is that you are actually trying to accomplish.

Comment: A common photodiode like a QSD2030 would probably work. I don't have any to test, I can only find IR photodiodes in my stash right now. I have some visible photodiodes somewhere, but they are so old that you probably can't buy them anymore. You will also need a comparator and a transistor to drive the buzzer.

Comment: Background: My car aircon recirculation button often turns off by itself. This happens when the aircon is cold enough. Problem is. When it turns off and the indicator light disappears, the pollution outside gets into my car and I can smell the pollution and my pm2.5 monitor registers 20x higher.

Comment: It does not look like a "button", it looks like rotary control set to leftmost position, which is marked "auto-off". Have you tried rotating it clock-wise to different position and see if it still turns off by itself?

Comment: It is separate auto and off. And the more it is turned clockwise, the stronger is the fan. And it still turns off even when set to the first two clicks after auto. And you can't turn it more because fan would be too strong. I only know when it is turned off when I can smell the diesels from other cars exhaust that gets inside the car and become trap. I really need an a buzzer that will sound when the lit goes off (and recirculation lost, meaning air from outside gets in).

Comment: Do you realize that recirculation means you are breathing your own CO2? and maybe occasional methane ;) It is only meant for quick warming up/cooling down and should not be left on for extended periods. Especially in winter when it results in windows fogging up.

Comment: There is only hot summer in my place, and our pollution from cars is too dense. You can literally breath carbon monoxide if you open the inlet to outside hence circulation is the safest option compard to black diesel exhausts through out the street.

Comment: So what specific photodiode is guaranteed to work when connecting to a transistor and buzzer? Can you give examples You can post it as Answer so we can discuss from there.

Comment: @Jtl Your car doesn't have an air filter for the cabin? Much of exhaust is particulates that a cabin air filter will remove.

Comment: @Jtl 1) What do you do when you have used up all the oxygen? 2) Would taking the indicator light out to get to its electrical wires be an option? Or perhaps you can get to the other end of those wires.

Answer (score 2):

This is a working circuit (I ordered and received some QSD2030 photodiodes). My test light is a 40+ year-old red LED with 6 mA through it. It is very dim compared to modern LEDs.

I can't absolutely guarantee that this will work for you, it will depend on the brightness of your indicator light and how well you can shield the sunlight. My test light (LED) is almost certainly dimmer than your indicator light. But, sunlight is very, very bright, you will need to shield from sunlight very well.

If the photodiode is too sensitive, you can reduce the value of R1.

I recommend using a car USB +5V power adapter as the power source. It will probably work with 12V. But, car 12V can have nasty noise on it and the voltage can vary quite a bit.

Edit: If a low-power buzzer is used, the transistor isn't necessary. A CEP-2242 would be a good choice, it doesn't need a transistor. https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/cui-devices/CEP-2242/102-1115-ND

Or, you can search Digikey. You want an internally driven "indicator". If it is externally driven (speaker), you will need to add an oscillator.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1Jj8h.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

Comment: Thanks. What is the 100 ohm indicator for? Do you know what kind of buzzer to replace with it so it sounds when the light turns off?

Comment: The 100 ohm indicator (lamp) was intended to be replaced with a buzzer. I updated my answer.